# Can't import sqlContext.implicits._ without an error through Jupyter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, apache-spark-sql, jupyter

When I try to use the `import sqlContext.implicits._` on my Jupyter notebook, I get the following error:

```
Name: Compile Error
Message: <console>:25: error: stable identifier required, but $iwC.this.$VAL10.sqlContext.implicits found.
       import sqlContext.implicits._
                         ^
```

I've tried this locally and it works, but this does not properly function when using it on my Jupyter Notebook server (which is hosted on ec2). I have tried importing different libraries involving that, but unfortunately can not get it to function.

Answer (score 6):

You need to instantiate a sqlContext like so:

```
val sqlC = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlC.implicits._
```

You should have seen this error:

> stable identifier required

Answer (score 2):

you have to use `val` keyword instead of `var` keyword. Since `val` is equals to `const` or `final` keywords.