# Limited Scala Syntax with Apache Toree Kernel in Jupyter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, apache-toree

```
OS X El Capitan 10.11.6
Spark 2.2.0 (local)
Scala 2.11.8
Apache Toree Jupyter Kernel 0.2.0
```

Per the instructions I received from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46747583/toree-on-jupyter-for-spark-2-2-0?noredirect=1#comment80963013_46747583), I've successfully included a `Spark - Scala` kernel to my Jupyter notebook by using [this Toree installer](https://anaconda.org/hyoon/toree). However, I have noticed that the Scala syntax is very limited. Here are two examples:

**1. Not able to manually create a DataFrame**

The following code works in a terminal Spark shell:

```
val test = Seq(
        ("Brandon", "Erica"),
        ("Allen", "Sarabeth"),
        ("Jared", "Kyler")).
    toDF("guy", "girl")
```

But when trying to run in Jupyter with a `Spark - Scala` kernel, I receive the following error:

```
Name: Compile Error
Message: <console>:21: error: value toDF is not a member of Seq[(String, String)]
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value toDF'?
       toDF("guy", "girl")
       ^
```

**2. Not able to call column names with certain syntax**
It seems as though the Jupyter `Spark - Scala` kernel does not recognize columns when called with `$"columnName"`, but does recognize columns called with `df.col("columnName")`. The `$"columnName"` syntax throws the following error:

```
Name: Compile Error
Message: <console>:31: error: value $ is not a member of StringContext
   df.where($"columnName" =!= "NA").
```

I'm thinking that there is an high-level solution that will allow for all Spark Scala syntax to be used in Jupyter and look forward to the community's support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798657/cant-import-sqlcontext-implicits-without-an-error-through-jupyter) that also resolved my issues:

```
val sqlC = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlC.implicits._
```

Running this at the beginning of the notebook has alleviated all syntax limitations I was previously having.